# How do I test Online Contribution Receipts?

Tags: contributions, receipts

How do I test the edits I make to online contribution receipts? Is making a test contribution using the online form the only way, or recommended way?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you only TEST LIVE; Just delete the contribution that you have created afterwards; a $1 LIVE transaction that you can follow all the way though into your Payment Processor - will guarantee you that things are working as expected.

Added: You'll have tokens for total_amount etc, right? This is how you test it. You can also plug in TEST credentials for your payment Processor in LIVE payment processor config. Then you can test LIVE CiviCRM pathways with fake VISA cards.

Comment: Totally agree. a real $1 test proves way more.

Comment: I have already tested that my payment processor works. What I am looking to test, are incremental changes to the template for the receipt (its not exactly pretty by default!). There is no way to edit it and instantaneously see how the result looks in gmail, etc. Is making a contribution again and again the only way to see the result? Why is there not a 'send a test' button for the message templates for receipts? Thanks!

Comment: It's the only real test :-)

Comment: You'll have tokens for total_amount etc, right? This is how you test it. You can also plug in TEST credentials for your payment Processor in LIVE payment processor config. Then you can test LIVE CiviCRM pathways with fake VISA cards.

Comment: "Why is there not a 'send a test' button?" Please contribute this feature if you can. I agree it would be helpful. Or fund a developer/partner to do same. Ping us if you would like an esimate for this.